# Typescript generic parameters assertion

Tags: typescript

I want to do a **compile-time** assertion on the following code:

```
interface FormFields {
  [K: string]: string | boolean | number;
}

function FormTextInput<
  FieldName extends keyof Fields,
  Fields extends FormFields
>(fieldName: FieldName) { ... }

// should throw compile-time error:
FormTextInput<'someNumberField', { someNumberField: number }>('someNumberField')

// should NOT throw error:
FormTextInput<'someStringField', { someStringField: string }>('someStringField')
```

so that `FormTextInput` always throws an error if `FieldName` refers to a non-string value of `Fields`

Is it possible do to this at compile-time with Typescript? I have seen some docs on `asserts` ( https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions ) but it doesn't seem it was meant to be used for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define helper utility which picks keys with string value from source type:

```
type PickKeysWithStringValue<T> =
  { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? P : never }[keyof T];

type Test = PickKeysWithStringValue<{ foo: string, bar: number }> // results in "foo"
```

---

```
function FormTextInput<Fields extends FormFields>(fieldName: PickKeysWithStringValue<Fields>) {  }

// throws compile-time error:
FormTextInput<{ someNumberField: number }>('someNumberField')

// doesn't throw error:
FormTextInput<{ someStringField: string }>('someStringField')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFtXAgGwBMBnZAbwChlkBtAaQC5liwpQBzAXSZbZHeQAfZACN06fBDgghyEAFcsI6AG4KAXwoUwATwAOKAArAEAazoQdxAOrAwACwDKrDgDU4+eRAA8AFQB8yAC8VOS0hsigyKaW6DDIvtwJNIacyBAAHpAgJMwu-MgA-MgRTCAQAG7QyOo0MTpxCZxq2voovhAswSUm5pY2dk757O6ePmTIMOI8wwA0onBQZYrKUDWBAPQbyFCd8vhgpFEARFPox1ow8iAIYMDoMhjYHVkAkiB68mDeuAS5mdlck8cHgiMR-AAKGCgwgAOTgWAgTGMZgsVlsDmcfBGHi8Pxh4IAlGFNBQtsgHFB0AB3UgIdBYPTASQAWjuiPSUCpSwowJeYHen2+E2IDIgsJW0F+RGWSmq6khAHJRYiJXKoNLCIrCVpyYR0J0QIqwBT7FTqZzuQxeZgsPzBV9vCKxViOJqZtj1hDlS7hprtRQgA)

Comment: works great! But question: Is there a way to improve the error message? it just says Type '"someNumberField"' does not satisfy the constraint '"someStringField"'

Comment: Also I am sure this came up before, but if I change the order of the generics in the function to `<Fields, FieldName>` why can't TS infer the type of the second generic from the arguments of the function.

Would be nice to not need to specify the fieldName twice

Comment: Why do you need generic type parameter for field name?

Comment: I am doing some magic so the user can only pass fieldNames that match a certain type in Fields. To do that I need it as a generic

Comment: Can you add an example on playground?